# Service / API design patterns - which is the preferred approach?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I'm wrestling with two different design approaches to a fairly simple problem.

I have a service (in the generic sense, not Web/SOAP etc) that:

- Receives an `Input` class
- Uses `Input` to process and create an `Output` class that is essentially just data, all dependent on the Input data.

The two different design approaches are as follows:

- Use an `OutputCreator` class that knows how to create and populate the `Output` and leave the `Output` as basically a POCO. The  `OutputCreator` has all the processing logic, the `Output` is very simple and cannot be abused.
- Alternatively, pass the `Input` directly to a particular type of `Output` class. Each type of `Output` knows how to process the `Input`, so it supports behaviour also. The key `Output` data would be defined by an interface which each different type of `Output` would implement.

The first approach means I can make all the processing logic internal to my service. The second means I don't need the `Creator` class with that logic being encapsulated, but I potentially expose more (plus it may violate SRP).

Which approach is closer to best practice?

Thanks

Comment: There are some questions left here: Do you have many clients that connect to your service in a client-server like scenario? Do you want you service to be responsive? Do your clients expect a direct result of a call, i.e. something like Get-Methods can be called?

Answer (score 0):

This depends strongly on what you want to achieve.

If your service has to be somewhat responsive, a kind of queue seems to be adequate.

This means:

Your service receives `Input` and enqueues it to the `InputQueue`.

Then your `OutputCreator` periodically reads that queue from another thread,
creates your `Output` and puts it on the `OutputQueue`.
If this is possible and your result can be passed asynchronously, i.e.
through a message, your are done.

Adding to the Queue and removing can be done in threads, hence not blocking
the InputThread or the OutputThread when the corresponding queue is blocked.

If your `Input` expects `Output` as a result, the Proactor pattern will
solve this. This is more complicated to implement, but it is explained well
in the following PDF: [Doug Schmidt on Proactor Pattern](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CF4QFjAB&url=http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/proactor.pdf&ei=Lt8XUNeaBIzQsgacxoDQBw&usg=AFQjCNFoNeWioIF2nqgsmIsjIi403tXOhQ&sig2=fZ2CgSkyuu12a6dRWbV4Fg)
An example for Proactor can be a WebServer.

If you just need some dispatching, the Reactor Pattern (almost as described
above) is the solution of choice.  [Doug Schmidt on Reactor Pattern](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf&ei=KuAXUPPJHIfPtAb9-oDwCg&usg=AFQjCNHLIcRPZwBOARYZcxMI9aQn6XMonw&sig2=RvQXr19bUTocTEXt3-haOg)
Reactor is not very difficult to implement in C# or Java.
An example for a Reactor can be a central logging server that writes
Logentries from different clients to serverside log.

The most flexible is the Active Object Pattern, but it is the most difficult
to implement. It even decouples method invocation from method execution.
Read more here: [Doug Schmidt on Active Object](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf&ei=fuAXUPy5GMaLswarnYDICw&usg=AFQjCNH92aJsZ6V7h8crcodsk7w12Z8Psg&sig2=WfIFvmM6Dxl8ZmF-mDVAzQ)
An example for Active object is a CORBA ORB.

Comment: Mare - my question wasn't about threading, or queueing, sorry if it wasn't clear. It was much more about encapsulation of logic - where to put process logic - internally to the final data object, or in another class that understands how to build the data object. Does that make sense?

Comment: With respect to the idea of a service - ignore that part!! This is just a code component that has clients. I want to be a restrictive as possible in terms of what clients can do with the objects my component creates...

Comment: From your question it sounds like you wanted to know how to create a proper service that can handle requests from clients. You get Input, i.e. requests and you deliver Output, i.e. responses. My answer provides how you can achieve that in a proper way. But, really, I do not understand what you want to achieve with those restrictive Output objects. Please provide more information on that, perhaps in a new question.